# Logical architecture based on modules and SPI

Tags: design, java, object-oriented, modules

I'm looking for the most proper way to design a modular application with ServiceLoader.

**--MAIN IDEA--**

- module ***app.view*** | *exports* `app.view.View` interface that defines UI api
- module ***app.engine*** | *exports* `app.engine.Engine` interface that defines Engine (core functionality) api
- module ***app*** | (entry point) *requires* and *uses* `app.view`, `app.engine` in order to combine them into actual program

The app will be open for extension, anyone can add new implementations of `app.view.View` interface.

**--CONCERNS--**

Since `app.view` will be exported through *exports* keyword, it will be accessible in every other modules, also in unrelated ones. This feels like a design mistake. Is it?

On the other hand, if I'd change *exports* to *exports to* I could force it to be accessible only in related modules, but it will not be extension friendly anymore.

Is my design idea proper for that kind of application? Should I ignore my concerns? If so, why?

**--EDIT--**

I removed ability to extend `app.engine.Engine` just to simplify the case.

Each `app.view.View` implementation will provide new `javafx.scene.Scene` (which is basically whole UI "skin", as I'm working with JavaFX).

`View` interface looks like this:

```
public interface View {

    String name();
    
    javafx.scene.Scene createScene(Engine engine); //takes engine and maps buttons and ui functions to actual engine

}
```

Comment: Could you clarify please, would each `View` implementation be a different screen in the same UI, or would each one be an alternative UI for the whole app? And the equivalent question for `Engine`? Could you perhaps add some example methods for each of those interfaces as well, to help understand your design?

Comment: @justme I removed extendibility of `Engine` to simplify the case and added sample `View` interface methods. (please read post EDIT)

Answer (score 2):

I will try to address each of you concerns.

Exporting the `app.view` module with the *exports* keyword may not necessarily be a design mistake, as it allows for greater flexibility and extensibility. However, it does mean that you need to be careful about the interfaces and classes that you expose in the `app.view` module. You should only expose what is necessary for other modules to interact with the `app.view` module.

Using the *exports to* keyword instead of *exports* can provide some security benefits, but it would also make it harder for third-party developers to extend your application with new `View` implementations. This could limit the potential for your application to grow and evolve over time.

Overall, your design idea for the application seems reasonable. You are using the ServiceLoader pattern to allow for extensible `View` implementations, and you have defined clear interfaces for the `View` and `Engine` modules. As long as you are careful about what you expose in the `app.view` module and keep your design modular, I would say that it will be easy to extend and maintain your application over time.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your updated question correctly, we have:

- `app.engine` module which defines an `app.engine.Engine` class and *exports* `app.engine`. There might be other classes in that package which the view or entry point needs to be able to access, and there might be some internal engine code in other not-exported packages within this module.
- `app.view` module which defines an `app.view.View` interface, *requires transitive* `app.engine` and *exports* `app.view`.
- `app` module which *requires* `app.engine` and `app.view` and *uses* `app.view.View`.

Now you'll need to provide some implementation(s) of the `View` interface (assuming the app will include one or more standard "skins" when you ship it). You haven't mentioned them explicitly in the question but I'm assuming they're in additional modules, e.g., `app.myspecificview`, which *requires* `app.view` and *provides* `app.view.View` *with* `app.myspecificview.SpecificView`.

In which case, I don't see much of a downside in `app.view` using *exports* instead of *exports ... to*, unless you actively want to prevent others creating new skins for your app. The only code that's being made visible by that is the `View` interface. It will only be accessible if someone *requires* `app.view` from their own module, and realistically, they'll only do that if they're planning to create a new skin.

Similarly, the *exports* in `app.engine` are only making visible the minimum that's needed to write a UI skin for the app (at least, if you're following [Sebastian's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/444445/103859)), and that's unlikely to cause any problems. In the worst case scenario, you might make a breaking change which means someone has to update their skin to keep it compatible with the latest version of your app - but in my mind that's still better than disallowing them to create any skins at all.

There is one place that *exports ... to* could still be useful in this scenario, and that's to hide the parts of the engine that only the entry point needs to be able to access. You could retain your original design of `app.engine.Engine` as an interface containing only the parts that `View`s need to be able to get to - the implementation would be in another package which is exported only to the `app` module. This way, only the entry point could instantiate the engine, and it would be possible to add methods to the implementation if there are other functions that only the entry point needs.